# Identify the area of Toast notifications from a windows 10 application

Tags: c++, notifications, windows-10, toast

I have an application which is performing screen sharing for presentations by scraping the area of the screen for the shared window. It identifies when other windows overlap that area and does not include that area in the scrape.

The problem is that Toast notifications are not being identified as "windows" and so when one overlaps the shared application the notification on the presenter's screen is shared, which we don't want.

Is there a way to identify the area of the screen occupied by any toast notifications, the Action Center, etc.? I'm not interested in manipulating or interrogating the contents, only in identifying the area they occupy so that I can apply the same exclusion login used for other windows.

The application is Java wrapping the C++ win32 API, which is all new to me, and solving this has been dropped into my lap, so I apologize in advance for lack of details.